# Changing class of all input fields if one input field is entered

Tags: javascript, validation, forms

I have a page with 3 tables:

```
<table id="t1">
  <tr>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="id" /></td>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="perDate" /></td>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="t2">
  <tr>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="lostFound"  /></td>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="lostDate" /></td>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="item" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="t3">
  <tr>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="check" /></td>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="reason" /></td>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="chkDate" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, I have a validation script where if I just change the class to 'required' then it will make that input field required.  The problem I am having is....I only want to require a field if another field in that table is filled out, otherwise the field is not required.   Ex: If t1 - name is filled in then I want to change the class of t1 - id, t1 - perDate, and t1 - email to 'required', and leave all of the other classes for t2 and t3 untouched.  I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction with some sort of javascript code that would make this possible.  thanks for all the help, and if more info is needed, please ask.

Comment: Are you using a JS library like jQuery or MooTools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you blur out of the "Name" input, you require the adjacent inputs to be required if they provided a name.  But also don't forget to make them not required if they go back and decide to clear that name field like so:

```
$('.t1 input[name=name]').blur(function(){
    var $depends = $('.t1 input[name=id], .t1 input[name=perDate], .t1 input[name=email]');
    if($(this).val() != "")
        $depends.addClass('required');
    else
        $depends.removeClass('required');
});
```

Also, if you're trying to change the required attribute if *any* of the controls have data, you would do something like this:

```
//blur even on each input in t1
$('.t1 input').blur(function(){
    //store as variable
    var $t1in = $('.t1 input');
    var hasData = false;
    //check all inputs and if one has data, set variable and exit
    $t1in.each(function(){
        if($(this).val().length > 0){
            hasData = true;

            //exit loop
            return false;
        }
    });
    //if any of the controls has data
    if(hasData)
        $t1in.addClass('required');
    else
        $t1in.removeClass('required');
});
```

Comment: @pixel , Thanks, I am going to try this, but would this work, say, if they filled out t1 - id only....would it make the other fields required?

Comment: @Jonathon: Ok.  So if i'm understanding correctly, do you want it so that any if any field in t1 is populated, it will require the entire section, right?

Comment: @pixel , Thanks for the quick response, yes, that is correct, if any field in t1 is populated, it will require the entire section.

Comment: @Jonathon: Hey, see my updated answer. If any control in t1 loses focus, it will check all the inputs in t1, determine if any has a value, and then as soon as it hits a value it will continue and add required classes to ALL inputs otherwise if everything is empty it will remove the "required" class.  Keep in mind you could also wrap this in a function that you could pass "t1" or "t2" to and use `$(this).find('input')` to set the child input controls.

Comment: @pixel , do i need any extra jQuery plug-in when using this?

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use jQuery, or any other JS library, you could very easily do something like this:

```
$('#t1 input[name=name]').change(function()
{
    var dependents = $('#t1 input[name=id],
                        #t1 input[name=perDate],
                        #t1 input[name=email]');

    if (this.value.length > 0)
    {
        dependents.addClass('required');
    }
    else
    {
        dependents.removeClass('required');
    }
});
```

Comment: Far better: `dependents.toggleClass('required', this.value.length > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.required { border:2px solid red }
</style>

<script>
function checkFilled(field) {
    var fields = field.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        fields[i].className = field.value != '' ? 'required' : '';
    }
}
</script>

<table id="t1">
  <tr>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="name" onkeydown="checkFilled(this)" onkeyup="checkFilled(this)" onchange="checkFilled(this)" /></td>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="id" /></td>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="perDate" /></td>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="t2">
  <tr>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="lostFound" onkeydown="checkFilled(this)" onkeyup="checkFilled(this)" onchange="checkFilled(this)" /></td>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="lostDate" /></td>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="item" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="t3">
  <tr>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="check" onkeydown="checkFilled(this)" onkeyup="checkFilled(this)" onchange="checkFilled(this)" /></td>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="reason" /></td>
    <td></td><td><input type="text" name="chkDate" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It's useful to add all `onkeydown`, `onkeyup` and `onchange`. `onchange` is useful for pasting in the field.